# Peterson's vs. Bakery Algorithm

Tags: process-scheduling, synchronization

From my CS course, the Peterson's Algorithm and the Bakery Algorithm both are solutions which satisfy the 3 requirements of any solution to the critical section problem. a) What are their adv/disadv over each other , and b) if they already solve the critical section problem, why do we need semaphores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) what are the advantages/disadvantages over each other?

According to [the lecture note: Sections 17.4.1 and 17.4.3](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/classes/465/notes.pdf), we can summarize as follows:

1. The *original* Peterson’s Algorithm works with only 2 processes.
2. The Peterson's algorithm requires multi-writer registers while the Bakery algorithm uses only single-writer registers.
3. Both algorithms are starvation-free. Furthermore, the Bakery algorithm offers a strong near-FIFO guarantee.
4. Both algorithms work with atomic registers. However, the Bakery algorithm works with even weaker registers (*safe* registers actually, see [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#bakery)).
5. The Bakery algorithm uses unbounded registers. Nevertheless, this problem can be fixed.

> b)  If they already solve the critical section problem, why do we need semaphores?

A Semaphore is a generalization of mutual exclusion locks. Each Semaphore has a capacity, denoted by $c$ for brevity. Instead of allowing only one thread at a time into the critical section, a Semaphore allows at most $c$
threads, where the capacity $c$ is determined when the semaphore is initialized. (See the book "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" by Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit; Section 8.5).

Answer (score 0):

They don't work for multiprocessors and modifying them to solve them is a hassle.

Whereas semaphores are simply mathematical methods to create process precedence graphs for concurrent execution.

Just an integer variable, that's it.